# eventListnener to dynamic created content with random unique ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have modals that is created dynamically and with random ids, which works perfect.

But I need to add an eventListnener to the span tags so I can close the modal that has the span tag that is clicked.

I got this working on one span tag with this code.

```
$('div[id^="myModal_"] span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
})
```

But when I click on the other span, both my Modals close because it is higher up in the DOM hierarchy and don't have four parent elements.

My whole code looks like this, anyone got any suggestion on how to add eventlistnener to listen for clicks on the span tags on the current modal and close that modal?

```
function new_modal(head, content){

var random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

var modal_html = '<div id="myModal_'+ random +'">' +
 '<div id="outer">' +
  '<div id="inner">' +
   '<div id="top">'+head+'</div>' +
    '<span><img class="btnClose" src="#"></span>' +
   '<div class="modalCnt">'+content+'</div>' +
    '<div class="btn">' +
     '<span class="btnText">OK</span>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div> <!-- Inner -->' +
 '</div> <!-- Outer -->' +
'</div>';

$('body').append(modal_html);

    return 'myModal_' + random;  
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

    modal1 = new_modal("<h3>Headline 1</h3>", "<p>Content 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non metus libero. Integer sollicitudin felis vel lobortis sagittis. Vestibulum eget sapien est. Curabitur ex nibh, tincidunt id est ut, venenatis congue nisi.</p>");
    $('#' + modal1).show();
    modal2 = new_modal("<h3>Headline 2</h3>", "<p>Content 2 </p>");
    $('#' + modal2).show();
});
```

Comment: Do you want to close modal by clicking `both span` on each modal ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [closest()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) method instead of to many `parent()` and change the selector for following:

```
$('#myModal_'+ random +'" span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('#myModal_'+ random).hide();
})
```

Actually your selector isnt working cause [[attribute^=value]](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_beginning_value.asp) selects all element with a specific attribute, with a value beginning in a specific string.

Comment: Great, needed to remove the extra " in random +' ". But otherwise it works just as I wanted. The selector was really throwing me off, its the first time I'm working with unique ids.

Comment: Glad to help you